# using timestampz method in typescript and postgreSQL

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

`enter code here`I am trying to use this as a basemodel that extends other models but when I create an entity, it adds data to the updatedAt and deletedAt column even when I have not done any update or deleted the entity

BaseModel

```
import { BaseEntity, CreateDateColumn, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

export class BaseModel extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  deletedAt: Date;
}
```

then I inherited it with ClassRoom

```
import { E_CLASSROOM_STATUS } from './../types/ClassRoom';
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  OneToOne,
} from 'typeorm';
import { BaseModel } from './BaseModel';
import { Grade } from './Grade';
import { Student } from './Student';
import { Teacher } from './Teacher';

@Entity()
export class ClassRoom extends BaseModel {
  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ enum: E_CLASSROOM_STATUS })
  status: string;

  @Column()
  remarks: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Teacher, (teacher) => teacher.classRoom)
  @JoinColumn()
  teacher: Teacher;

  @ManyToOne(() => Grade, (grade) => grade.classRooms, {
    cascade: ['insert', 'update'],
  })
  grade: Grade;

  @OneToMany(() => Student, (student) => student.classRoom)
  students: Student[];
}
```

ClassRoom.service

```
// Create class room
export async function createClassRoomService(
  createClassRoomDTO: CreateClassRoomInput
): Promise<ClassRoomResponse> {
  const grade = await Grade.findOneBy({
    id: Equal(createClassRoomDTO.gradeId),
  });
  if (!grade) throw new Error('Grade not found');
  const classRoom = await AppDataSource.createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(ClassRoom)
    .values({ ...createClassRoomDTO, grade })
    .returning('*')
    .execute();
  return { classRoom: classRoom.raw[0] };
}
```

ClassRoom.controller

```
// Create ClassRoom
export async function createClassRoom(
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  try {
    return res.sendStatus(201).send(await createClassRoomService(req.body));
  } catch (error: any) {
    let message;
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      message = error.message;
    } else {
      message = String(error);
    }

    if (
      message.includes('duplicate key value violates unique constraint') &&
      error.detail.includes('name')
    ) {
      message = 'A ClassRoom with this name already exists';
      return next(createHttpError(400, message));
    }

    return next(createHttpError(500, message));
  }
}
```

classRoom.routes

```
import express from 'express';
import {
  createClassRoomSchema,
  updateClassRoomSchema,
} from '../../types/ClassRoom';
import {
  createClassRoom,
  deleteClassRoom,
  getAllClassRooms,
  getClassRoom,
  updateClassRoom,
} from '../../controllers/classRoom/ClassRoom.Controller';
import validateResource from '../../middlewares/ValidateResource';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', getAllClassRooms);

router.get('/:id', getClassRoom);

router.post('/', validateResource(createClassRoomSchema), createClassRoom);

router.put('/:id', validateResource(updateClassRoomSchema), updateClassRoom);

router.delete('/:id', deleteClassRoom);

export default router;
```

Please any help to why it is so?

Comment: Please post the entire code - how you define both the base model and concrete model, how you create the entity, how you query it, and where you find that "data has been added".

Comment: `timestamptz` is not a "method", it's a data type.